# Access denied when writing files to network drive

Tags: windows-7, windows, permissions, file-permissions, network-drive

[Cannot map network drives using 'net use' while elevated as an administrator](https://superuser.com/questions/697100/cannot-map-network-drives-using-net-use-while-elevated-as-an-administrator) is the previous question, and this is somewhat of a follow-up.

So here's what I've done over the last few months:

1. Mapped two network drives as normal user (username Joey, only user on JOEY-LAPTOP, my laptop)
2. Get "Access Denied" error whenever I try to write to files on the network drive - can read and execute just fine but cannot save files to it etc.
3. Unmapped network drives, ran Windows Explorer as administrator and remapped them - this fixed nothing
4. Tried using `net use`, that failed, [so I asked this question](https://superuser.com/questions/697100/cannot-map-network-drives-using-net-use-while-elevated-as-an-administrator) and received the answer
5. Mapped network drives using `net use` as administrator, then used `takeown` to transfer ownership to user Joey on system JOEY-LAPTOP (`JOEY-LAPTOP\Joey`)
6. Still get access denied error

I'm not trying to do anything across different computers - I'm only using my laptop. I'm pretty sure this has been happening since I wiped my laptop and reinstalled my OS.

Comment: Ensure your user names/passwords match (or are correctly supplied) for user "Joey" on both machines (if not on a domain).  Check the settings for both the Share itself and the folder being shared, as well as the files with-in.

Answer (score 3):

Figured out the answer:

I went to my Users directory (the top level share) and went to Properties > Advanced Sharing > Permissions. I added permissions for my user (`JOEY-LAPTOP\Joey`) for full control, and I guess that fixed it.

Thanks @techie007 for the comment.